# Animal Crossing new leaf dream suite

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How do I get the dream suite if I already found Isabelle sleeping like one or two months ago but I didn't go to the mayors chair afterwards? Do I get a second chance of somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to go to the mayor's chair, and choose it from the list of public works projects.